# Java Enums Issue

Tags: java, enums

I have a below program, My enum has value "2" but it just doesn't work the way it is expected. Any help will be appreciated.

```
package com.deepak.streams;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Demo2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (Scores.scoreMap.containsKey("2")) {
        System.out.println("Contains Value");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Does not contains Value");
    }
}

public enum Scores {

    PASS(1), FAIL(2), MATRIC(3), PROMOTED(4);

    private Integer alias;
    private static final Map<Object, Scores> scoreMap;

    Scores(Integer iAlias) {
        alias = iAlias;
    }

    static {
        final Map<Object, Scores> tmpMap = new HashMap<Object, Scores>();
        for(final Scores scores : Scores.values()) {
            tmpMap.put(scores.alias, scores);
            tmpMap.put(scores.name(), scores);
        }
        scoreMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(tmpMap);
    }

    public Integer getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public static Scores getStudentScoreEnum(Integer intVal) {
        return getScores(intVal);
    }

    public static Scores getStudentScoreEnum(String strVal) {
        return getScores(strVal);
    }

    private static Scores getScores(Object objVal) {
        if(null != objVal && !scoreMap.containsKey(objVal)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Value: " + objVal);
        }
        return scoreMap.get(objVal);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The question isn't clear, what's the expected behaviour, and what's happening instead ?

Comment: @Dici - If you look at the main method, My enum clearly has key "2" in it. When I am running it, it is not able to show the actual result i.e it's not printing "Contains Value".

Comment: Scores.scoreMap.containsKey(2)

Comment: Your enum has an Integer key 2 in it, you are querying for a String value "2". As Integer != String, the result you get is correct and expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map key is an `Object`:

```
    final Map<Object, Scores> tmpMap = new HashMap<Object, Scores>();
```

This means it can be any Java `Object`.  When you use `put` twice:

```
    tmpMap.put(scores.alias, scores);
    tmpMap.put(scores.name(), scores);
```

your map will now contain two new keys.  The first one is an `Integer` since the argument, `scores.alias`, is an `Integer`.  The second one is a `String`.

When you perform a lookup on `"2"`, it won't find the `Integer` key, because `"2"` is a `String`, and `"2".equals(x)` is `false` for any `x` that isn't a `String`.  Put simply, the string `"2"` does not equal the `Integer` 2.

If you really want to look up keys using `String` representations of integers as the key, you'll need to use a `String` as a key when adding to the map.  That is:

```
tmpMap.put(scores.alias.toString(), scores);
```

Your best bet is to declare the map as having a `String` key, instead of `Object`, so that problems like this will be caught at compile time--unless you *really* want to be able to use both `Integer` and `String` values to do your lookups.

Comment: He also could be using Integer as the key, which is what I would possibly prefer, depending on what I want to achieve

Comment: Don't agree with the last part. It has nothing to do with the type of the map. He's just mistakening the return value of `scores.name()` and the alias he defines. This can work perfectly with this map, although it's not particularly elegant. Note that `Map.get` is unchecked (takes an `Object` as parameter) so you last sentence is wrong

Comment: @Dici Of course the error is not because of the type of the map.  But while he doesn't **need** to make the key type `String`, it would be best if he does, unless there's a good reason not to.  We don't know just what he's trying to accomplish in his full program, but it probably doesn't involve using the literal `"2"` as a key; it seems more likely that he's asking for input from the user, and the user is allowed to enter either a number or the enum name.  But we're all just guessing here.

Comment: @ajb Maybe, then it's just an opinion. But the bit about compile-time error is still wrong, since `Map.get` is unchecked

Comment: @Dici It would have caught an error on `tmpMap.put()` with an integer as the first parameter.  Also, if he makes the key type `String`, he should also change the type of the `getScores` parameter.

Comment: @ajb right, misunderstood you. Guess he just did that to avoid having two maps

Answer (score 0):

Your map contains a binding for the integer `2`, not the string `"2"`. The name mapping will be `"MATRIC" -> enumValue`.